# Mock method get arguments array_include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Lets suppose i have a `class` like this:

```
class Splitter
  def split args
  end
end
```

And another class like this one:

```
class Text
  def initialize
     Splitter.new.split([["first","234nnmer"],nil])
     Splitter.new.split([["second","ewfr32$"],nil])
  end
end
```

How would you **test** that when `Text.new` is called:

**Splitter is called twice,one time with the argument `"first"` and another time with the argument `"twice"` in the argument array**

I tried:

```
 it "calls Splitter with arguments 'first' and 'second'" do
     expect_any_instance_of(Splitter).to receive(
            :split).with(array_including("first"))

     expect_any_instance_of(Splitter).to receive(
            :split).with(array_including("second"))

     Text.new
 end
```

This test doesn't work for me because I get errors like:

```
   -["array_including(first)"]
   +[["first","234nnmer"],nil]
```

Link: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#argument-matchers

Answer (score 1):

```
expect_any_instance_of(Splitter).
to receive(:split).with([array_including("first"), nil]).once

expect_any_instance_of(Splitter).
to receive(:split).with([array_including("second"), nil]).once
```

The following might also work:

```
array_including(array_including("first"))
```

Comment: Sorry but somehow when i try `array_including(array_including("first"))` it returns me a error:  `-["array_including(array_including(first))"]
       +[["first","234nnmer"],nil]`

Comment: It seems like it transforms `array_include` to an String